# Meteorjs Data array not rendered at first template rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm working on a project in Meteorjs, but I have a problem in rendering some data.

The problem is: At the first template render, there is no html. Then I switch the template to a 'MAP' view and go back to my 'LIST' view, and now there is the html with the different trainers.

I have a `routeController` that does some extras operations to get some `data` from `Algolia`, and push it into a `data.trainers` array.

For example (in `trainers_controller.js`):

```
data: function() {
    var trainers_tab = [];
    // algolia
    var client = algoliasearch('XXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
    var index = client.initIndex('myindex');

    if(Meteor.user()) {
        tab = Trainers.find({});

        tab.forEach(function(trainer) {
            index.getObject(trainer.doctor_id, function (err, content) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }

                // geoloc address
                // TODO : retrieve training exact address

                // push to array
                trainers_tab.push({
                    objectID: content.objectID,
                    name: content.name,
                    city: content.city,
                    speciality: content.speciality,
                    photo: content.photo,
                    about: content.about,
                    email: content.email,
                    phone: content.phone
                    //address:
                });
            });
        });

    }


    var data = {
        params: this.params || {},
        trainers: trainers_tab
    };
return data;
}
```

I have exactly what I need in the `data.trainers`.

Next I try to render the trainers into my `template` with the base method of

```
{{#each trainer in trainers}}
     Do some stuff in html yeah !
{{/each}}
```

I determine and can switch the view with the `{{>TemplateDynamic }}` spacebar of Blaze.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Are you exposing `data.trainers` through a template helper? If not, then the template doesn't know where to get that data from.

Comment: Hi maxko87. For some professionals reasons i can't post all the code.
No, my data.trainers are not exposed through a template helpers, i tried to had it, and that's not changing anything.

Like I said, at first rendered, the page dosen't show any datas. But at the second rendered, there are here and i have all my datas displayed. (And don't to acces to it within a template helpers...).

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I had a template helpers to retrieve my data from the client-side into template. Same problem, the first render there is no data, then switch template, and after datas rendered... Suggestions ?

Comment: I would guess it is related to Algolia's client-side caching, although I did not dive into the code to test its behavior. A reasonable explanation is that the callback is called synchronously when the data is in local cache, thus `data.trainers` is populated before the `data` function returns. During the first render it is not the case and the property remains an empty array at render time.

Comment: I tried to add a var canRender = false, and set it to true when all the data was loaded. If the canRender != true, there is no render of the template.
But still doesn't work..

Comment: If you won't post your full code (nobody is asking you to post sensitive info, just the related codes like route, helpers, pub/subs, onCreated(), onRendered() etc.), I doubt you'll get a solution. There are multiple different solutions depending on how you do stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where your function is defined, you can either use a `ReactiveVar` and set it as data in your `data` function, *i.e.* instead of returning `data`, set the object to your ReactiveVar:

```
Template.foo.onCreated(function() {
  this.myData = new ReactiveVar(null);
});

Template.foo.onRendered(function() {
  // Run your data function here
  const data = {
    params: this.params || {},
    trainers: trainers_tab
  };
  this.myData.set(data);
});
```

Finally, retrieve the data with a helper:

```
Template.foo.helpers({
  data: function() {
    return Template.instance().myData.get();
  },
});
```

That way, if your template is rendered *before* the data is retrieved, it will be updated and re-rendered once myData is set in your function.